# Webpack 3 not excluding node_modules

Tags: webpack, webpack-3

What's wrong with my webpack.config.js here, as it's failing to exclude node_modules. I've found similar posts about this issue with previous versions of webpack, but the fixes don't work as the syntax is different...

```
    module.exports = {
        context: __dirname,
        entry: './src/index.js',
        output: {
            path: __dirname + '/public/assets/',
            publicPath: '/assets/js/',
            filename: 'bundle.js'
        },

        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    include: /src/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: [
                        {loader: 'style-loader'},
                        {loader: 'css-loader'}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.ejs$/,
                    include: /src/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: [
                        {loader: 'ejs-simple-loader'}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    include: /src/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: [
                        {loader: 'jshint-loader'}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.jsx$/,
                    include: /src/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: [
                        {loader: 'babel-loader'}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using rules that require the `pre` value.

Your code should read:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./foo.js",
    output: {
        filename: "./bar.js"
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                enforce: 'pre', // updated value
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    { loader: 'jshint-loader' }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Source: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#ruleenforce

Comment: Thank you, @robinCTS. 

I don't understand why this was downvoted. I replicated OPs problem, provided the solution, and added the source.